# How to calculate the amount of different 'combinations of classes' of a variable depending on a other variable?

Tags: r

```
CustomerID  MarkrtungChannel    OrderID
1   A   1
2   B   2
3   A   3
4   B   4
5   C   5
1   C   6
1   A   7
2   C   8
3   B   9
3   B   10
```

Hi, I want to know which combinations of marketing channels  are used by how many customers .

How can I calculate this with R?

E.g. The combination of Marketing channels A and C is used by 1 customer (ID 1)

the combination of Marketing channels C and B is also used by 1 customer (ID 2)

And so on...

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Is the order important? Eg. Is `A C` same as `C A`? If you have more marketing channels do you want to investigate the sub-groupings as well? Eg. If a user followed `A B C` do you also care about `A B`, ` A C`, `B C` ? Also, customer with ID 2 is using `B` and `C` and not `A` and `B` as you mentioned.

Comment: Hi, the order is for my current case not important. (Even though it could be interesting in the future). The same applies for the subgroups. And Thanks for the hint with Customer 2 - i gonna edit it. Its channels are as you mentioned B and C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and here's a tidyverse way.

```
library(tidyverse)
data.df%>%
group_by(CustomerID)%>%
summarize(combo=paste0(sort(unique(MarkrtungChannel)),collapse=""))%>%
ungroup()%>%
group_by(combo)%>%
summarize(n.users=n())
```

counting the number of people using each combo at the end.

Comment: thanks, it works out very well (after i had some trouble installing the package)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it multiple ways. Here is `data.table` way:

```
# Here is your data
df<-structure(list(CustomerID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                              3L, 3L), MarkrtungChannel = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                      1L, 3L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
               OrderID = 1:10), .Names = c("CustomerID", "MarkrtungChannel", 
                                           "OrderID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
df[]<-lapply(df[],as.character)

# Here is the combination field
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,Combo:=.(list(unique(MarkrtungChannel))), by=CustomerID]  
# Or (to get the combination counts)
df[,list(combo=(list(unique(MarkrtungChannel)))), by=CustomerID][,uniqueN(CustomerID),by=combo]
```

Comment: Hey Jean, thank you for this suggestion! Given, that I have about 4million customers I cannot see how I could adapt this method to my dataframe...

Comment: For 4 million customers, you need to start using `data.table`